# How to autofill a cell down based on a variable value 'n'

Tags: vba, function, excel, autofill

I am calculating a variable number of rows in cell C1, which I need to autofill down by, in cell B1. For example, if C1 returns the number '3', then I need to autofill cell B1 down three rows.

Any way to do this using a logic function or VBA?

Answer (score 0):

```
Range("B1").Resize(Range("C1").Value,1).FillDown
```

Comment: I have one more question for you.... How do I code VBA to autofill down to the last row from the current selected cell? Sorry I am a total VBA n00b.

Comment: Down to the last row in the sheet? `Range("B1").Resize(Rows.Count,1).FillDown`

Answer (score 0):

Put this in B2 and copy down:

```
=IF(ROW()<=$C$1,$B$1,"")
```